# R Markdown - how to export to PDF file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm having trouble to export R markdown to PDF file (or Word).

I opened a new 'R markdown' file, and just use the template and rename it to test.Rmd.

However, this won't work for me:

```
render("test.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document")
Error in abs_path(input) : The file 'test.Rmd' does not exist.
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="test.Rmd": The system cannot find the file specified
```

It's strange because I saved test.Rmd in my desktop.

Also, I tried click 'Knit' > 'Knit to PDF' > gives me this error:
output file: test.knit.md

```
pandoc.exe: test.utf8.md: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Execution halted
```

Methods I tried but no help:

```
install.packages('tinytex')
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

Can anyone help me with this? BTW I'm using enterprise computer so it's not possible for me to download any external app outside of R.

Comment: Try starting a fresh session and instead of manually rendering use the defaults ie simply knit and see what happens. Otherwise, are you in the same directory as where test.rmd is?

Comment: I tried simply 'knit' but the error message is still 'no such file or directory'. By in the same directory, do you mean which is in the same directory as test.rmd?

Comment: Just try this(hard to know without taking a look at the markdown file and/or access to the computer): Just open a new RMarkdown file, do not edit anything and simply knit. It will ask you to save it somewhere, do that(save with no extensions in the name, it is assumed you're using Windows).

Comment: Did that. Yes it asks where do I want to save it. However, the saved file is the R markdown file, which is .Rmd file. I can't change the file type to word or pdf.

Comment: You should save as .Rmd first then knit. After knitting, you will have a pdf if you have miktek/texlive installed and on path.

Comment: Tried but not working. I do not have miktek/texlive installed, but I don't need it if I want to export to word.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding about your end goal, I am unable to help further and hope someone else helps solve the issue. I have frankly never converted rmd to Word.

Comment: I'm able to figure this out by changing the directory of the file from desktop to 'R Studio' file. However, do you know how to use data from another R file when knitting in R markdown?